# extracting error information from rails log files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, logfile-analysis

i am developing on 5 different rails projects, plus also refactoring some (moving from older rails versions to 2.3) - what is the best way to extract the error information from the logfiles, so i can see all the depreciation warnings, runtime errors and so on, so i can work on improving the codebase?

are there any services or libraries out there you can recommend, that actually help with rails logfile parsing?

Answer (score 11):

Read about `grep` linux command.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/

I don't know what error log format is in Rails, but I guest every row with warning or error contain "warning" or "error" word.

Then it would be like this:

`grep -E "error|warning" logfile.txt`

for bot error and warnings

`grep "error" logfile.txt`

for errors

`grep "warning" logfile.txt`

for warnings

and if you want to see new errors and warnings in real time, try this

`tail -f logfile.txt | grep -E "error|warning"`

`tail -f logfile.txt | grep "error"`

`tail -f logfile.txt | grep "warning"`

Hope I could help you ;) and I hope that I'm not wrong about logs format in Rails

Comment: ok, i just tried an inital regex on how to parse rails log files which seems to work: (Processing.*?)(\n\n\n|\z) - this is seperating the requests into processable pieces...

Comment: You really want a **-A**  (after context) or **-C** (both before and after context) line includer in your grep statements so you get the trace as well. For example: grep -C7 -E"error|warning" logfile.txt

Comment: @Tsagadai +1 for that. The error line without context is useless :)

Answer (score 3):

I've found the [request-log-analyzer](http://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer) project to be very useful.

You can certain grep the log to find errors and dump them out, but this does an excellent job of gathering all the information about the different actions and how long they take.

Here's some [sample output](http://wiki.github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer/sample-output).

This is the first thing I run when I get a call saying "my site is slow and I need help fixing it."

Hoptoad and/or Exceptional are great for ongoing errors, but they don't track log running requests.  Something like New Relic is good for that.

Comment: great! thanks a lot for this. after searching for request-log-analyzer i also came up with more rails logging: http://whynotwiki.com/Rails_/_Performance http://jacqueschirag.wordpress.com/2008/10/15/rails-log-analyzers/

Answer (score 1):

I use hoptoadapp, http://www.hoptoadapp.com/pages/home there is a free flavor, it logs your error messages to their database, and they provide an easy to use interface. All you have to do is install this plugin: http://github.com/thoughtbot/hoptoad_notifier.

It won't help for past errors, but it is great for isolating problems with a currently running app.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, this looks like a really handy web application. i will take a look into that.