# Publish logs on web

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need ability to analyze rails log files on web browser. Are there any plugins for this aim?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077211/extracting-error-information-from-rails-log-files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push all of your log on [Graylog2](http://www.graylog2.org/). After you can see all of your log in a web browser. and filter it.

Comment: It require java and mongodb :(

Comment: but it's works. You can create a little url_rewrite to read your log file directly instead.